# Something is using my camera on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: webcam

My camera is always active and it shuts down(led on camera) when I open-close cheese web-camera program. Is someone using my camera or just a bug? I have heard that many can control  web-cameras. On windows it is working fine! Web camera is genius facecam 113. How to stop the application doing this?

```
dimitris@dimitris-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo ps aux | grep /dev/video0 
[sudo] password for dimitris:  
dimitris 12661  0.0  0.0   4688  2036 pts/0    S+   18:21   0:00 grep --color=auto /dev/video0
```

Comment: What is the laptop and most importantly what is the camera name, brand, model ? It could be a driver bug.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo ps aux | grep /dev/video0`.

Comment: @Helio .... dimitris 12661  0.0  0.0   4688  2036 pts/0    S+   18:21   0:00 grep --color=auto /dev/video0

Comment: @solsTiCe  it is Desktop http://www.geniusnet.com/wSite/ct?xItem=16749&ctNode=159&mp=1

Comment: @Dimitris: Please, **edit** your answer and put the output as **code**.

Comment: Instead of `grep`ping the process list for `/dev/video0`, it would be better to look for processes with open references to that file: `sudo fuser -v /dev/video0`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that someone is using your camera, you should probably disconnect from the Internet just to see if it stops. If it doesn't, then it's probably a program on your computer, or perhaps a compatibility problem since on Windows it behaves differently.

Comment: I closed the internet and camera is still active

Comment: @Dimitris nothing is using your camera  whenever you do grep with ps ps lists grep to the process list and shows it

Comment: @bolzano  I typed sudo ps aux | grep /dev/video0   when  cheese webcamera is open the results are same.  List is empty. So still something can use my camera